# How to manage learning many languages at the same time?

Tags: learning-methods, bilingualism

Being interested in learning 2 or 3 languages at the same time, I wonder if there are some best strategies to use for better results (regarding time management, things that we should focus on more, etc).

Comment: Reated /but not an exact duplicate): http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/67/can-learning-spanish-and-french-simultaneously-improve-your-knowledge-in-both-la

Comment: Are the languages you want to learn related to each other?

Comment: @michau Not necessarily. I want to know some strategies that I can use regardless of how the languages I picked up are related to each other.

Comment: @ettanany If you want a completely general answer, I don't think it's possible to say much about something like "things that we should focus on more". This is definitely dependent on actual languages you want to study. Maybe you should focus your question just on the time management, as this is more likely to have a general answer.

Comment: @michau I got your point, but I think that all languages have some common skills and sub-skills that need more focus, and this is what was that part of my question about.

Comment: @ettanany I'm learning completely different and unrelated languages, including e.g. Mandarin and Greenlandic. I can't see how the fact that I'm learning one of the languages can influence the way I'm learning the other. Can you? I don't know what kind of answer you're expecting.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried this myself. My trick is to try to learn a bunch of *similar* languages at one time.

Among European languages (I haven't done this with Asian or African languages), English, Dutch, German, and the Scandinavian languages are similar. For instance, a certain liquid is "water" in English and Dutch, "Wasser" in German, and "vatten" in the Scandinavian languages.

Another language group is French, Italian, Portuguese and Spanish,(the Latins), in which "water" is eau, aqua, agua, and agua, respectively. In these cases, "if you learn one, you can learn all." This can save a lot of time, if you were planning to study all four languages one by one, anyway.

Comment: Did you experience interference for words that weren't similar? I mean, things such as using the right word, but from the wrong langauge.

Comment: @michau: Yes, of course. But these instances have been rare enough not to be bothersome.

Answer (score 1):

This can be difficult when learning languages that are not related to each others nor to the languages you already know.

I experienced that myself when I tired to learn Japanese and Kiswahili (an east African language) at the same time as a native speaker of German with knowledge in English, French and a little Bulgarian. No similarities whatsoever. After some time it got me totally confused to the point where I had to drop one language.

In my case I had teachers for both languages but they were different persons and did not train just me. If you had a single teacher for two languages it could be easier.