# Is there a known limit to how many languages a person can be fluent in?

Tags: multiple-languages

I wonder this because I'm not sure whether it'd be too hard to separate all the languages at a certain point.

Comment: If you are worried about confusing several languages that you are learning, please check [What are some techniques to better differentiate between the two languages?](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/8/what-are-some-techniques-to-better-differentiate-between-the-two-languages), [How can I avoid confusion or interference when studying two similar languages?](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/542/how-can-i-avoid-confusion-or-interference-when-studying-two-similar-languages) and similar questions.